# How setup a application for facebook comment plugin?

Tags: facebook

I have setup facebook comment plugin on my site and i have created app too.now i want to setup this application for this comment plugin..I tried.but not working..can you help me?

Code given by developpers-

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}">
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you have already included the XFBML on your website (e.g., example.com) as follows:

`<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="example.com" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>`

To moderate the comments plugin, you need to add the meta tag to the  section of your website:

`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}" />`

Replace `{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}` with the appropriate app ID listed in the Facebook Developer App (https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

You can see a full example of the comments plugin here (view source):
http://www.myfbse.com/winery/storybar.html

Documentation for the comments plugin is here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/